ZFS ARC ghost memory usage
Are arcstats:mru_ghost_evictable_metadata and arcstats:mfu_ghost_evictable_metadata the number of bytes stored in RAM by the arc ghost list?
If so, is this memory usage also accounted for in the arcstats:size and arcstats:arc_meta_used number?
If not, how could we determine the memory used by the ghost list?

You can check this Q/A: https://superuser.com/q/1137416/409497

@RomeoNinov That doesn't say anything about the ghost memory usage (only ghost hits are mentioned)
